# The time it takes light to reach different points on a plane

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light

Imagine there is a light source which is held perpendicular to a plane. Is there a difference in the speed light hits a part of the plane?

Comment: Why should there be a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about the time and speed that light hits the plane. Since the lightsource is perpendicular to the plane (but the light itself is not a laser, but a normal lightsource, that spreads), light will hit the plane:

1. in the shortest time where it is closest to the plane
2. longer time where it is not hitting the plane perpendicularly

Light moves at speed c in vacuum, when measured locally always.

It is the path that will be longer, since your lightsource is not a laser, and though the lightsource is perpendicular to the plane, but the photons will be emitted from the source towards the plane in certain angles, and so they will hit the plane in different angles.

The perpendicular angle will have the shortest path, and the other angles will have longer paths towards the plane, but the speed of light will be the same c.